# Identifying gaps in a table or set of integers

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I would like to identify which IDs have been deleted from a table. For instance, if this is my `client` table:

| client.client_id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 4 |
| 6 |
| 8 |
| 9 |

I want to discover the values 3, 5, 7.

What I'd like to do is on the lines of the Python `range` function:

```
WITH "no_gaps" AS (
    SELECT RANGE(MAX(client_id)) as "client_id"
    FROM client
)
SELECT no_gaps.client_id
FROM no_gaps
WHERE no_gaps.client_id NOT IN (SELECT client_id FROM client)
```

The context is a BusinessObjects report on a PostgreSQL 9 database - I can only provide a single `SELECT` statement (with CTEs if I want).

Comment: Note that all 9.x versions (from 9.0 to 9.6) are [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: It's maintained by a vendor, and they have announced they will upgrade… at some point.

Comment: of course, it transpires the IDs didn't get created in arithmetic sequence, but about 1 time in 8 there's a gap… so the gaps don't imply deletions anyway. oh well!

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL has a `generate_series` function:

```
WITH "max_id" AS (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS "max_id"
    FROM client
)
SELECT all_ids AS "deleted_ids"
FROM
    max_id,
    GENERATE_SERIES(1, max_id) AS "all_ids"
WHERE all_ids NOT IN (SELECT id FROM client)
```

This query produces the desired results: the missing IDs from the gaps in the table.